# How do you modify/replace an S3 image using Python and the Chalice library?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, chalice

I'm writing a lambda function that gets triggered everytime a user uploads an image to S3. The function's primary purpose is to compress the image, possibly renaming it in the process as well. To achieve this, the function is to fetch the newly uploaded image, compress it, upload the newly compressed image, and delete the original file:

```
@app.on_s3_event(bucket=settings.BUCKET_NAME, events=['s3:ObjectCreated:*'])
def compress(event):           
    # download the resource
    s3.Bucket(settings.BUCKET_NAME).download_file(key, local_file_path)

    # compress the image
    ...

    # rename the file, if necessary (change extension, etc.)
    ...

    # upload the new image
    s3.Object(settings.BUCKET_NAME, output_path).put(Body=open(compressed_path, 'rb'))    

    # remove original image
    s3.Object(settings.BUCKET_NAME, event.key).delete()
```

So if I upload an image named `sample.png` to S3, it gets compressed and renamed to, say, `sample.jpg`; and `sample.png` will be deleted afterwards.

The problem, however, is that the solution would result to an *infinite recursion*. The reason is that the uploading of the compressed image would invoke the lambda function again, thereby causing the downloading again, thereby compressing the already compressed image, thereby uploading it again. Ad infinitum.

A friend of mine suggested two possible solutions: **cache the name of the compressed image** by storing them somewhere on a separate S3 bucket file, and prevent cached filenames from being uploaded more than once; and to **modify the exif/metada of the compressed image** so the lambda can tell which files have already been compressed, indicating that the function should not proceed, which would prevent the compression from happening again.

The first idea is prone to issues that may arise when multiple files are uploaded to the server simultaneously, theoritically speaking at least. The second idea may require a third-party library, like [piexif](https://piexif.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), but is the one I'm currently considering.

Do you have a better way of approaching this issue? Or am I even doing the compression thing (apart from the recursive uploading and downloading) right in the first place? I mean, perhaps I can compress S3 images without having to do the download-compress-upload-delete routine.

Comment: Is it always going to be a png -> jpg conversion? If so, you can use the `suffix` parameter of on_s3_event (see https://chalice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#Chalice.on_s3_event) to filter out the unwanted object creation events.

Comment: Sometimes a JPEG also gets converted to a JPEG.

Comment: Then I would  suggest separating the images into two buckets - original and processed. You don't have to worry about recursion (or the input in general), and you get to keep to originals if you will need to reprocess them in the future (granted, I'm just making up a use-case). If you want to keep it in a single bucket, you placed the processed ones in a directory, does that work?

Comment: That's a different use case. The uploader would expect the compressed images to be in the same directory as the one to which he uploaded the original images, because that path will be used by a different program.

Answer (score 0):

Hey since you are converting it in another format , it will be easier if you would call your lambda function for uploaded file format hence prevent unnecessary infinite loop.

Suppose images are being uploaded in .jpeg format and you compress and convert it into .png. Now, since the newly updated image is in .png format your lambda function will not be triggered.